# Season end dates and rewards

Tags: league-of-legends

For the current season of League of Legends, when is the cut off time for reaching a certain rank for rewards, and what are the ranks requires for what rewards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cutoff is on **November 11, 2014**.

http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/competitive/end-season-rewards-and-new-master-tier